# PHP and JS popup not working like it should

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, popup

So I was *programing* 2 popups for my 3D modeler website. I want to make both of the popups work. But one of them (the upload a model one) doesn't work. For some reason, I think it's the JS, rather than HTML.

I tried renaming functions and HTML code. It, well, did nothing. Please help! (this is all my code for the
`index.php` file).

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Gr8brik homepage</title>
    <style type="text/css">
    #overlay {
      display: none;
      position: fixed;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    }

    #popup {
      display: none;
      position: fixed;
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      width: 80vw;
      height: 90vh;
      background-color: white;
      z-index: 1;
    }

    #popup-iframe {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
    }
    #popup-iframe2 {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
    }
    
    button {
        color: #0000ff;
        border: none;
    }
    button:hover {
        color: #add8e6;
    }
    </style>
    <script src="scripts.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Welcome to Gr8brik!</h1>
    <ol>
    <li><a href="/index.php">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="/modeler/index.php">Modeler</a></li>
    <li><a href="/account/login.php">Login</a></li>
    </ol>
    <input id="searchbar" onkeyup="search_models()" type="text" name="models" placeholder="Search models">
    <ol id='list'>
    <div class="models">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Filename</th>
            </tr>
            <?php
            $files = glob('users/*.xml');
            foreach($files as $file){
                $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($file, 0, true);
                echo '
                <tr>
                    <td>'. basename($file, '.json') .'</td>
                </tr>
                ';
            }
            ?>
        </table>
    </ol>
    </div>
    <p>Gr8brik is a 3d Lego builder that's all online. No istallation needed</p>
    <div class="button">
    <form id="popup-button">
    <input type="button" value="Create a model" name="create" />
    </form>
    <form id="popup-button">
    <input type="button" value="Upload a model" name="upload" />
    </form>
    </div>
    <video id="tutorial" controls width="640" height="480" poster="" >
    <source src="tutorial.mp4" type='video/mp4;' />
    <embed src="tutorial.mp4" wmode="opaque">
    <param name="wmode" value="opaque" />
    </video>
    <div id="overlay"></div>
    <div id="popup">
    <iframe src="modeler/modeler.htm" id="popup-iframe"></iframe>
    <div id="overlay"></div>
    <div id="popup">
    <iframe src="account/upload.php" id="popup-iframe2"></iframe>
    <script>
    const form = document.getElementById("popup-button");
      const overlay = document.getElementById("overlay");
      const popup = document.getElementById("popup");

      form.addEventListener("click", function () {
        overlay.style.display = "block";
        popup.style.display = "block";
      });

      overlay.addEventListener("click", function () {
        overlay.style.display = "none";
        popup.style.display = "none";
      });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please create a [**Minimal** reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). if php is needed, add the `php` tag. else, create an HTML only snippet representing the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You have `<form id="popup-button">` twice. The [id](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id) attribute must be unique within the HTML page:

> The id global attribute defines an identifier (ID) which must be unique in the whole document. Its purpose is to identify the element when linking (using a fragment identifier), scripting, or styling (with CSS).

This means your `const form = document.getElementById("popup-button");` selects the first match which is why your second button doesn't have an `EventListener` attached to it. Consequently, it doesn't open the modal.

You could add a class instead:

```
<form class="popup-button">
```

Then your JS will be:

```
const forms = document.querySelectorAll(".popup-button"); 
forms.forEach((form) => {
   form.addEventListener('click', () => {
      overlay.style.display = "block";
      popup.style.display = "block";
   });
});
```

This will solve your immediate problem but this is **not** how you use the `<form>` tag. I would reccomend you bind your JavaScript to the `<button>` elements instead. Your code needs a lot of reworking but keep trying. Use [this](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-build-a-modal-with-javascript/) tutorial to help you with your modal.